# html form-php question

Tags: php

This is my html form and below this i included my php text.

But I am not getting correct output,i don't no where the problem is ?

I also included the output ,please suggest me what shuld i do?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Entering data into text
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
Entering data into text
</h1>
<form  action="text.php" method="post">
What is ur name ?

<input  type="text" name="data" />


<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my php text:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Reading data from textfields
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
reading data from text field
</h1>
Thanks for answering,
<?php echo $_POST["data"];?>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
reading data from text field
Thanks for answering,
```

problem is that ,data send is not included after response of sever
please help me as fast as possible

Comment: Can you print what you get with `print_r($_REQUEST)` in text.php?

Comment: i am soory ,will you please explain a little more

Comment: I am new in php ,please help me

Comment: That's exactly what @amitchd is trying to do. Please, as he asked, post the resulting output from `print_r($_REQUEST)` in text.php =)

Comment: If you create a text file `info.php` which only content is `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` do you get any output?

Comment: yes it shows all php information about version,installation and functions etc

Comment: You are accessing the form, then clicking send, correct?

Comment: 1. Are you sure PHP is installed?

2. Are the files in the same directory and the PHP file is named "text.php"

3. Print out all POST data to make sure the data is actually being sent
        print_r($_POST);

Comment: reading data from text field 
Thanks for answering, fariz

Comment: i made a new program and that is also working,sending my new prog output,i am happy yaar                                         reading data from text area 
The name of students you entered are: 1.fariz 
2.hari 
3.raaj 
4. 
shilpi

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak for my own experience, but this works on *my* server. I'd suggest, then, that one of the following is true:

1. Your server isn't set up to handle php (though this would surprise me), also, as @gAMBOOKa noted (in the comments), if your server's not set up to handle php the script wouldn't output anything other than the raw text-contents of the php script, literally `"<?php echo $_POST["data"];?>"`.
2. You're trying to access the pages through the filesystem (`file:///path/to/file.html`), rather than through your server (`http://localhost/file.html`).

If '2' is correct, move your web-page and php script into a directory within your server's document root, on *nix this could be something like `/var/www/directoryName/` and access the page via `http://localhost/directoryName/dataEntryForm.html`. If you're on Windows, with IIS it could be `C:\inetPub\directoryName\` accessed, as above, with `http://localhost/directoryName/dataEntryForm.html`.

Incidentally, please forgive me for not linking to a demo of the page running, it's just that I'd prefer not to run the risk of exposing my server to, presumably, vulnerable scripts.

Comment: If the web server is not configured for php, shouldn't it output `<?php echo $_POST["data"];?>` ?

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: yeah, it really should, but I use '[not] set up to handle php' as a euphemism for, among other things, 'not set up properly.' Also, I didn't think of that... **edited in,** and my thanks! =)

Comment: @gAMBOOKa : he will only see it if he tries to view the page source. In the rendered page, it'll be invisible.

Comment: @JB: Why would it be invisible? To the browser, it's just plaintext.

Comment: @JB, @gAMBOOKa is correct. If you create a `file.php` file, add the php "<?php echo $_POST["data"];?>" to that file, save it and open it in a browser from outside of the web-document tree it will show the plain-text.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa : Not if he saved the file PHP file in a .html file, or if his server serves PHP files as HTML. I just tested opening an HTML file containing the php text in Firefox, Chrome and IE, and they all make the PHP snippet invisible.

Comment: yes sir ,you are right,when i tried to run my prog through http://localhost:8080/text.html and enter the data ,i got "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\websites\text.php on line 13
" .please tell me how to fix this error

Comment: @fariz, usually that implies a syntax error somewhere before the line named as causing the error. Unfortunately I can't *see* an error anywhere, and, as I said, it works fine on my server. Um, perhaps if you put a `<?php ?>` as the *very first line*? I seem to recall this used to be necessary, but I'm not sure of it any more. And it is, at best, a random guess, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: I can't belive this ,it is working sir, i can't explain how happy i am , really much much thanks to all of you,You know it has been six hours on this such a small program,and i seached a lot of site for answering my question and finally i got all of you,thanks dear, hey i am sending my out put

Comment: @fariz, no problem. If the question has been resolved, and an answer here proved useful to that end, could you accept that answer? If the answers here did *not* prove useful, could you post an answer detailing what you did to resolve the question, and accept *that* answer? (To accept your own answer, though, you'll maybe have to wait a little while, I think.) Two other things: **1)** to 'accept' an answer click on the '✓' beside the helpful answer. **2)** you're quite welcome, I'm glad to have been of assistance =)

Comment: actually sir first of all i was accessing it directly from html file and i comitted a mistake in my ini file ,i didn't include my directory name,thats the reason thanks sir ,see you later ,have a nice day to all of you

Comment: @fariz, the price you pay for assistance from Stackoverflow is contributing back to the community =) I'd suggest posting that **comment** as an **answer** detailing *exactly* what you did to resolve your problem. Up-voting any answers that were helpful to you. Also, it's just 'David' (or, preferably, '@David'), the 'sir' is appreciated, but unnecessary =)

Comment: @David +1 for being a good sport. @fariz: David's right, it's generally a good practice to write and accept your own answer as the correct one, if no other satisfactory answers are available. Otherwise it may confuse anyone else who finds this thread.

Comment: i am having problem to run servlet ,please help me how to to run it,i don't know ,how to create xml file to run a servlet

Comment: @fariz: that's a separate question entirely, please search for existing questions that might answer your question; if no questions/answers can be found **[ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)**.

Answer (score 0):

Your full code is like this and I tested it, working perfectly.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Entering data into text
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
Entering data into text
</h1>
<form  action="text.php" method="post">
What is ur name ?

<input  type="text" name="data" />


<input type="submit" value="send" name="btn_save" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**text.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn_save']))
{


         $data=$_POST['data'];
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>
Reading data from textfields
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
reading data from text field
</h1>
Thanks for answering,
<?php echo $_POST["data"];?>
</body>
</html>
```

working perfectly.